# Scraping ASP website using cURL with manual redirection

Tags: php, curl

I need to scrape an ASP website using cURL. My hosting does not allow me to turn off safe_mode or open_basedir. That's why CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated (it throws an error "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set").

I tried to implement some workaround but after several unlucky days starting to be desperate. I am wondering how to change the code below to contain manual redirection instead of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION:

```
include_once __DIR__.'/simple_html_dom.php';
define('COOKIE_FILE', __DIR__.'/cookie.txt');
@unlink(COOKIE_FILE); //clear cookies before we start

define('CURL_LOG_FILE', __DIR__.'/request.txt');
@unlink(CURL_LOG_FILE);//clear curl log
class ASPBrowser {
    public $exclude = array();
    public $lastUrl = '';
    public $dom = false;
    /**Get simplehtmldom object from url
     * @param $url
     * @param $post
     * @return bool|simple_html_dom
     */
    public function getDom($url, $post = false) {
        $f = fopen(CURL_LOG_FILE, 'a+'); // curl session log file
        if($this->lastUrl) $header[] = "Referer: {$this->lastUrl}";
        $curlOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate',
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 9,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36",
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => COOKIE_FILE,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => COOKIE_FILE,
            CURLOPT_STDERR => $f, // log session
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        );
        if($post) { // add post options
            $curlOptions[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $post;
            $curlOptions[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        }

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlOptions);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        $this->lastUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // get url we've been redirected to
        curl_close($curl);

        if($this->dom) {
            $this->dom->clear();
            $this->dom = false;
        }
        $dom = $this->dom = str_get_html($data);

        fwrite($f, "{$post}\n\n");
        fwrite($f, "-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        fclose($f);

        return $dom;
    }

    function createASPPostParams($dom, array $params) {
        $postData = $dom->find('input,select,textarea');
        $postFields = array();
        foreach($postData as $d) {
            $name = $d->name;
            if(trim($name) == '' || in_array($name, $this->exclude)) continue;
            $value = isset($params[$name]) ? $params[$name] : $d->value;
            $postFields[] = rawurlencode($name).'='.rawurlencode($value);
        }
        $postFields = implode('&', $postFields);
        return $postFields;
    }

    function doPostRequest($url, array $params) {
        $post = $this->createASPPostParams($this->dom, $params);
        return $this->getDom($url, $post);
    }

    function doPostBack($url, $eventTarget, $eventArgument = '') {
        return $this->doPostRequest($url, array(
            '__EVENTTARGET' => $eventTarget,
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' => $eventArgument
        ));
    }

    function doGetRequest($url) {
        return $this->getDom($url);
    }

}
```

(Credits: Andrey http://256cats.com/scraping-asp-websites-php-dopostback-ajax-emulation/)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` info variable, as that returns the URL that it would *otherwise* had redirected to if you'd allowed it. Added in PHP 5.3.7.

Note that the exact response code 3xx also affects how the HTTP request method is supposed to change or not change when you follow a redirect. See details in the HTTP spec, [RFC 7231 section 6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4).

The libcurl docs for [CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html).